# You need to build Spark before running this program error when running bin/pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-view-engine

I am getting started with Spark.

I am getting an issue when starting spark.

I downloaded from spark official website, I am trying to quickstart from this https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/quick-start.html

I have downloaded, setup sparkhome., and when I tried running ./pyspark from bin directory I get this error :

```
soundarya@soundarya:~/Downloads/spark-1.5.0/bin$ sudo ./pyspark
[sudo] password for soundarya: 
ls: cannot access /home/soundarya/Downloads/spark-1.5.0/assembly/target/scala-2.10: No such file or directory
Failed to find Spark assembly in /home/soundarya/Downloads/spark-1.5.0/assembly/target/scala-2.10.
You need to build Spark before running this program.
soundarya@soundarya:~/Downloads/spark-1.5.0/bin$
```

Can anyone help me to figure out this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use source distribution you have to build Spark first. You can find details in the [Building Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html).

Otherwise just download a binary distribution (select pre-built) from downloads:

[image]

Also don't use outdated documentation. You can use either the latest:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest

or version specific

http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried running it. 

15/11/09 14:28:03 ERROR NettyTransport: failed to bind to /192.168.0.109:0, shutting down Netty transport
15/11/09 14:28:03 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.BindException: Failed to bind to: /192.168.0.109:0: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries!

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.net.BindException: Failed to bind to: /192.168.0.109:0: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries!

Comment: I downloaded  spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin

Comment: Whats in your conf/spark-env.sh file? Did you try opening up a spark-shell first? (bin/spark-shell)

Comment: When I tried running spark-shell I got error : 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000bff80000, 716177408, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 716177408 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/soundarya/Downloads/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/hs_err_pid16684.log
soundarya@soundarya:~/Downloads/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin$

Comment: that's because you are not having sufficient memory on your machine. What is executor memory/driver memory that you are allocating? and how much memory are you having on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

Download the pre-build version of spark like zero323 suggested. Also, It is not a good practice to run spark in sudo mode.

Comment: Hi, I tried downloading as suggested : spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.4 (prebuild version)..but still i m held up with errors..
 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000007d5500000, 716177408, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 716177408 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/soundarya/Downloads/spark-1.5.0/hs_err_pid18440.log

Comment: How much memory do you have on your machine? Its a JVM Heap error and has nothing to do with spark. You can try setting the spark.driver.memory and spark.executor.memory in the conf/spark-defaults.conf file. Or simply do a export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx1g from your terminal.

Comment: I did export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx1g ; Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1g
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
>>>
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

Comment: "There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue. "- How much memory are you having on your machine?

Comment: Hi AkhID, I have posted it as seperate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check space in your spark folder name like spark 2.4  then remove it and make spark-2.4 will fix issue